# JQuery scrollLeft still show zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have easy code I want to use to us arrows instead of scroll bar but I have problem sith scrollLeft function. It stll shows me zero. Can you advice me what can be problem?

```
/* SIDE SCROLL */

var leftOffset = $('.categories__list').scrollLeft();

$('.right-arrow').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(leftOffset);

})
```

This is my code on index.php:

```
    <section class="categories">
        <ul class="categories__list">
            <a href="" class="left-arrow"></a>
            <li class="categories__items">
                <ul class="categories__list-nested">
                    <li class="categories__items-img"><a href="categories__link"><img src="/bazar/assets/img/pocitace.png" alt="" class="categories__img"></a></li>
                    <li class="categories__items-nested"><strong><a href="categories__link">Počítače</a></strong></li>
                    <li class="categories__items-nested"><a href="categories__link">Počítače</li></a>
                    <li class="categories__items-nested"><a href="categories__link">Monitory</li></a>
                    <li class="categories__items-nested"><a href="categories__link">Notebooky</li></a>  
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
     </section>
```

UDPATE:

I made it by this way finally:

```
    var scrollEnd = $('.categories__list').width();

    $('.right-arrow').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $('.categories__list').animate({scrollLeft: scrollEnd}, 1000)
    })

    $('.left-arrow').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.categories__list').animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 1000)
    })
```

I was confused bcz on w3school example for scrollLeft they used alert and it was working.

Comment: Why did you turn this off? `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Comment: `alert(leftOffset);` will always shows `0` because you take it's value on page load and never update that value

Comment: @Justinas and how can I show its real value in some position? I think it is not working at all on my page, bcz if I set up to hide arrow when scrollLeft > 0, it does not make anything.